# ffmpeg x11grab inputting improperly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing

I have the stock ffmpeg install from the xbps repository. I've used it before, but am on a new system.

Running "ffmpeg x11grab -video_size 1280x800 -framerate 60 -i $DISPLAY output.mkv" yeilds no errors, but when I watch the video it is a mess switching between workspaces and with only partly rendered programs.

Taking other inputs such as webcam work fine, and different encoding methods don't change anything (though webm flat out doesn't work, but that's not a problem for me).

I've tried what's here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg

Only other thing to note is that I use i3 as a dm, which shouldn't be a problem, but figured I'd state it just in case.

EDIT: 
I was using compton for composite, and that was where my issue lied...
https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/381

Thanks!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I had a similar issue and fixed it by setting the desktop rendering to 'marco + compton'. This was noticed first when I played fullscreen video and had tearing. I don't know about Arch though.